# Closed form solution to maximizing the area of a rectangle inscribed in a rectangle with rounded corners.

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> Given a rectangle with length $L$, width $W$, corner radius $R$, and
> $L\ge W\ge 2R$, find the inscribed rectangle with the greatest area.

Taking the rounded rectangle as horizontal, I wrote the expression for the area of the inscribed rectangle based on the angle, $x$, between the horizontal axis and a line from the upper right radius center to the upper right corner of the inscribed rectangle. I set the derivative to be $0$ and got $a\cos x-b\sin x+\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x=0$. Is there a simpler closed form solution than that of a $4$th degree polynomial solution?